# How to pass different DB contexts from two derived classes to the base class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I am working on an ASP.Net Core API which will be hosted on OnPrem or Azure.

I have two DB contexts, `KeyVaultDB` and `SQLDB`. Both have the same tables.

I have an interface:

```
public interface ISecretsProvider
{
    Dictionary<string,string> GetSecretNames(string env);
    string GetSecret(string key);
    bool SecretsExistForEnv(string ev);
}
```

This  is implemented in a base class:

```
public class SecretsProvider : ISecretsProvider
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> GetSecretNames(string env)
    {
        var result = _context.KeyVaultVersions.Select();
        ...
        ...
    }

    public virtual string GetSecret(string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool SecretsExistForEnv(string env)
    {
        var result = _context.KeyVautlVersions.Select();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I have two derived classes:

```
public class KeyVaultSecretProvider : SecretsProvider
{
    public override string GetSecret(string key)
    {
        ....
        ...
    }
}

public class SQLSecretProvider : SecretsProvider
{
    public override string GetSecret(string key)
    {
        ....
        ...
    }
}
```

In my `Startup.CS`, based on an environment variable, I do dependency injection of either of the derived classes:

```
var envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("");

if(envVariable.Equals("true")
{
    services.AddTransient<IsecretsProvider, KeyVaultSecretProvider>();
}
else
{
    services.AddTransient<IsecretsProvider, SQLSecretProvider>();
}
```

And in a different class:

```
public class ConfigProvider
{
    private ISecretsProvider _secretsProvider;

    public ConfigProvider(ISecretsProvider provider)
    {
        _secretsProvider = provider;
    }

    public JObject GetConfig(string env)
    {
        var result = _secretsProvider.GetSecretNames(env);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't know how to assign the `_context` in the base class. In the startup, if `KeyVaultSecretsProvider` is injected, `KeyVaultDB` context must be used to fetch secretnames in the base class.

If the `SQLSecretsProvider` is injected, the `SQLDB` context must be used to fetch secretnames in the base class.

Comment: How `_context` is passed to the classes? You can use the same approach as secret provider. Register appropriate context class in DI based on the flag

Comment: Yes. I thought about that too but how do you assign the correct context to the _context variable. You have to declare what type _context is before assigning it. That is where the issue is.

Comment: Constructor of SecretsProvider class should have context as parameter. Same as ConfigProvider constructor has ISecretsProvider as parameter